# Did Akira Toriyama state recently that Gohan is the strongest Saiyan?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

Some websites/YouTube channels claimed Akira Toriyama recently stated Gohan is the strongest Saiyan. This statement would be in the context of Gohan getting a new transformation called Gohan Beast, so it's somewhat believable, though it also could be a false rumor.

Did Akira Toriyama state recently that Gohan is the strongest Saiyan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the plausible references is probably **from the *Dragon Ball Super: Super Hero*'s movie pamphlet that contains Akira Toriyama's commentary** (dated back to May 28, 2022).

[image]

<sup>Image courtesy of [Yahoo! Japan News](https://news.yahoo.co.jp/articles/b4e32a8e963aad9bf7f73ceebfc3357dabaa0504)</sup>

The first question is:

> Ｑ：悟飯とピッコロ、そしてレッドリボン軍にフィーチャーした狙いは何でしょうか？
> Ａ：**悟飯は、じつは誰よりも強い**。と言われながら、近頃はなかなか活躍する機会がありませんでした。[...]

Translation:

> Q: What was your aim in featuring Gohan, Piccolo, and also the Red Ribbon Army?
> A: **Gohan is actually stronger than anyone else**. But he has not had much of a chance to play an active role in recent years. [...]